# .htaccess url rewrite issue with dot

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create my url structure like::
facebook i.e. facebook.com/?pageid=122
For which I am using htaccess mod rewrite as:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_\-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@]*)$ /$1.php?$2 [QSA,L]
```

so I may translate pages like site.com/home/?pageid=22 into site.com/home.php?pageid=22

The code above works fine except that if I try to add dot like

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_\-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@\.]*)$ /$1.php?$2 [QSA,L]
```

The .htaccess breaks. I need dot so I may pass emails too i.e. 
site.com/home/?email=sohaib.dmc@gmail.com

Please help

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but RewriteRule cannot match query string directly like you attempting to do -- only with help of RewriteCond. Please check the manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the backslash before the dot. Since it's not considered as a special character inside brackets in a POSIX regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You need scape the question mark because it's a special character:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_\-]+)/\?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@\.]*)$ /$1.php?$2 [QSA,L]
```

> The question mark makes the preceding token in the regular expression optional. E.g.: colou?r matches both colour and color.
>   http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html